# physics of javelin throwing in box2d

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to make a javelin throwing game in libgdx using box2d but with the physics of box2d the javelin lands exactly as thrown and not on its head.
I've tried applying angular Impulse but with every formula I have tried, it's still not real looking. is there anything in box2d that can solve this?

```
private void throwJavelin() {
    PolygonShape rect = new PolygonShape();
    rect.setAsBox(1.5f,0.05f);

    BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
    bd.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    Body javelin = world.createBody(bd);
    javelin.setUserData("javelin");
    javelin.setTransform(firingPos, angle);
    javelin.createFixture(rect,1);
    float velX = -( -MathUtils.cos(angle) * (strength/4));
    float velY = -( -MathUtils.sin(angle) * (strength/4));
    javelin.setLinearVelocity(velX, velY);

    float omega = -3/strength;
    javelin.applyAngularImpulse(omega, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [an online tutorial by iforce2d that explains how to do what you're asking](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/sticky-projectiles). I recommend checking out.

There's also [a video demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXovY2KTing) of what the results look like that I've also found useful and recommend checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Since the angle of the javelin is affected by drag/air friction and box2d does not handle drag you will have to come up with some workaround. Does it look natural if you in each step set the angle relative to the velocity vector?